# UIAlertView shown from background thread and with no delegate creates EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ios, uialertview, exc-bad-access

Here is my code:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"ERROR" message:@"JSON Parsing Error" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alertView show];
    [alertView release];
#endif
```

This code is executed in a background thread (responsible for parsing), and the error only happens every other time. Any idea on what is the problem here?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Dont mess with the UI from the background thread. Create a method and call that method on the main thread:

```
[someObject performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(showDebug:)
                             withObject:@"JSON Parsing Error"
                          waitUntilDone:YES];
```

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't execute UI code in separate thread.

> If your application has a graphical user interface, it is recommended
>   that you receive user-related events and initiate interface updates
>   from your application’s main thread. This approach helps avoid
>   synchronization issues associated with handling user events and
>   drawing window content. Some frameworks, such as Cocoa, generally
>   require this behavior, but even for those that do not, keeping this
>   behavior on the main thread has the advantage of simplifying the logic
>   for managing your user interface.

[Threads and Your User Interface](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/AboutThreads/AboutThreads.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000057i-CH6-SW21)