# UIAlertView crash in iOS 6

Tags: ios

I have this code:

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:title message:msg delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
[alert show];
[alert release];
```

The problem is this code crash before it shows the alert, I have tested it on lower iOS and it work but on iOS 6 it crash.

Comment: What is the crash log? Is title and msg initialized? are you conforming to the UIAlertView delegate?

Comment: Possible duplicated [a link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12408901/uialertview-causes-crash-in-ios-sdk-6-0)

Comment: this is really no error shown after..

Comment: check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12475858/1179680

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found the answer. I coded:

```
[alert performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(show) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
```

instead of

```
[alert show];
```

it crash because the process might not be performed in the main thread.

Source from:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/12475858/1179680

Comment: You mean you have replace [alert show];.....code with [alert performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(show) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];...right?

Comment: Its not working for me. I have also the same problem above. can you suggest or should I place one question for this?

Comment: @NavnathMemane : yes ...replace the [alert show]; ...in this case, it crash because the process might not perform in the main thread and the thread might be release by arc. Somehow, I am sure that this issue is about performing the action into the right and not nil thread. If you can show some more error or crash log we can take a look on it.